# How get secound line from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
    package Nauka;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class NaukaGamy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Akord> gamy = new ArrayList<Akord>();

        gamy.add(new Akord("C dur\n\n","  c', d, e, f, g, a, h, c"));
        gamy.add(new Akord("C moll\n\n","  c, d, es, f, g, as, b"));

        System.out.println(gamy.get(1));
```

Result is :     Nauka.Akord@7852e922

I'd to have secound line( C moll\n\n","  c, d, es, f, g, as, b) as solution. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need override `toString()` method in your class `Akord`. For example,

```
public class Akord {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return /*your fields to String*/;
    }
}
```